# Pipe output of an interactive script in shell

Tags: shell, npm-scripts, inquirerjs

I have a large Node repo with many npm scripts to manage the project. I created an interactive script with [Inquirer.js](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js) to act as an entry point to help developers to navigate. The script outputs the result in JSON.

To pick the selected npm script, and run it, I tried the following:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "node dev.js | jq .project | xargs yarn run"
    }
}
```

But instead of seeing the Inquirer script, this command stalls with an error message coming from `jq`.

What's the right way to wait for the result before piping to the next program?

Comment: There is no bug caused by a lack of waiting in your command. You can determine the real cause of failure by examining the `jq` error message.

Comment: @thatotherguy It happens immediately after `yarn dev`, the problem is not with the output, but something with the streams. Piping does not wait for the node script to finish.

Comment: What is the `jq` error message?

Comment: @thatotherguy

```
$ node dev.js | jq .project | xargs yarn run
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 2
(node:54803) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: write EPIPE
    at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:156:25)
    at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:147:3)
    [...]
(node:54803) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. 
```

Comment: This means that `node dev.js` is outputting something that isn't valid JSON. You can use `node dev.js | tee /tmp/dump | jq .project | xargs yarn run` to save a copy of the output to `/tmp/dump` so that you can inspect it manually.

Comment: @thatotherguy Yeah, it outputs the Inqurier.js prompt as expected: ```% cat /tmp/dump
? Which project do you want to develop? (Use arrow keys)
❯ Foo 
  Bar ```

Comment: That's a bug. Any questions for the user that is not part of the output is supposed to go to /dev/tty (or at least stderr). They can not be written to stdout.